# Are we allowed to be friends with or talk to the disbelievers?

Tags: halal-haram, friendship

I have a friend and I liked to talk to her but I have second thoughts now that I know she doesn't believe what I believe and that she is a pagan and she practices witchcraft and she believes in reincarnation. She is respectful of muslims, but she does not share our beliefs at all. Should I continue to talk to her? or should I just stop talking to her?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its allowed, in a condition that she's not fighting Muslims or Islam. But it's better to have a Muslims friend instead of a disbelievers.